# Below is my full fledged program and I am getting the error as "The multi-part identifier "dbo.JoinDateDiff" could not be bound"

Tags: sql-server

```
SET ANSI_NULLS on 
GO

Set quoted_Identifier on 
Go

create function dbo.JoinDateDiff 
    (@Joindate datetime)
Returns DateTime
As 
Begin 
    Declare @JoinAge Datetime 

    Select @JoinAge = DateDiff(Day, @Joindate, GetDate())

    Return @JoinAge
End

select 
    p.Employeeid, p.Joindate, r.EmployeeFirstname, r.Employeelastname,
    [dbo].[JoinDateDiff] 
From 
    HumanResources.Address p
Inner Join 
    HumanResources.Employees r on p.EmployeeID = r.EmployeeID
```

Comment: Is this the whole code? (and also, the whole question?)

Comment: Show the code that calls the function that produces this error message.

Comment: You must get the error when you call the function. Are you targeting the correct database? Did you create your function in master?

Comment: Must be something in how you are calling it. This works fine: select dbo.joindatediff('11/1/2015') as example

Comment: What is the real intent of this function?  @JoinAge is declared as datetime and DateDiff() returns an int

Comment: Thank you very much guys, I sorted it out. You guys are awesome.

Comment: Performance wise this would be much better as an inline table valued function instead of a scalar function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting this to an inline table valued function will reap some performance benefits. The function itself would look like this.

```
create function dbo.JoinDateDiff 
( 
    @Joindate datetime
) Returns table As Return
    Select DateDiff(Day, @Joindate, GetDate()) as JoinAge
```

And then the query to utilize this function would be something along these lines.

```
select p.Employeeid
    , p.Joindate
    , r.EmployeeFirstname
    , r.Employeelastname
    , jdd.JoinAge
From HumanResources.Address p
INNER Join HumanResources.Employees r ON p.EmployeeID= r.EmployeeID
cross apply dbo.JoinDateDiff(p.SomeDate) jdd
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send in your argument. The function does not evaluate based on naming. Try this.

```
select 
    p.Employeeid, p.Joindate, r.EmployeeFirstname, r.Employeelastname, 
    dbo.JoinDateDiff(p.Joindate)
From 
    HumanResources.Address p
Inner Join 
    HumanResources.Employees r On p.EmployeeID = r.EmployeeID
```